# Initialize a struct with a const default through copy

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, copy-constructor

I was trying to define a `AbstractOptions` struct that would hold some options that are used later on for a different class `Operator` with a concrete implementation `ImplementedOptions`. As a default value for `Operator`s default constructor I would like to use a previously defined `const ImplementedOptions DEFAULT_OPTIONS {1, 2}`. Additionally the `options` member of `Operator` should be modifiable.

My setup is something like this:

```
struct AbstractOptions {
  AbstractOptions() {};
  AbstractOptions(int val1, int val2) : _val1(val1), _val2(val2) {};
  AbstractOptions(const AbstractOptions &options) : _val1(options._val1), _val2(options._val2) {};

  int _val1;
  int _val2;
  virtual void implementation() const = 0;
};


struct ImplementedOptions : AbstractOptions{
  ImplementedOptions(int val1, int val2 = 4) : _val1(val1), _val2(val2) {};

  void implementation() const {/*whatever implementation*/};
};

const ImplementedOptions DEFAULT_OPTIONS {0,1};

class Operator {
  public:
  Operator() : _options(DEFAULT_OPTIONS) {};
  //ERROR -----^^^^^^^^: "Binding reference of type 'AbstractOptions' to value of type 'const ImplementedOptions' drops 'const' qualifier"

  private:
  AbstractOptions &_options;
};
```

This fails with the specified error. I would expect that the implemented copy constructor would copy the default and use that to create the instance but this seems not to be the case. If I would specify `_options` as `const AbstractOptions &_options` this would work as expected but I would like to be able to modify this struct.

It seems like there is a better way to achieve what I am trying but I'm somewhat at a loss. How could I refactor the code?

*Edit*: removed some copy-paste errors.

Comment: `AbstractOptions &_options` is a reference.  References bind to an alreadfy existing object and become an alias to that object, no copy happens.  Sound like what you need is a `std::unique_ptr<AbstractOptions>` and then you can get polymorphic behavior.  Also note that `ImplementedOptions` members `_val1` and `_val2` hide the `AbstractOptions` `_val1` and `_val2` members

Comment: `Options()` is not a copy constructor. It's not clear what role you expect a copy constructor to play here. Additionally, both `AbstractOptions` and `ImplementOptions` have their own `_val1` and `_val2`. This is not going to end well.

Comment: I think your basic approach is good, hide the implementation of options through an abstract baseclass (allows for dependency injection) though I havce some comments : Missing virtual destructor in baseclass, using virtual inheritance with public members, not recommended. Shadowing members in derived classes also not recommended, not using override in derived classes. Have a look here : https://onlinegdb.com/Cw2aAv1CT

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you're right about the hiding. That was an error in the question and is not present in the real code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer thank you for your suggestions. Can you elaborate on the significance of the virtual destructor?

Comment: virtual destructors are needed if you are going to destruct a derived object through a pointer to the (abstract) base class. This ensures that the destructor of the derived class will be called and not the destructor of the baseclass.

Comment: @RobertDeibel [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: I also recommend NOT to use a global variable for your options. But to inject an instance (by interface/abstract baseclass) to your operator. This also allows you to write unit tests that use different options very easily and it will make explicit which classes will use the options (better for maintenance later).

Comment: Questions posted to Stackoverflow must always show "real code". The only thing that results from posting fake code to Stackoverflow is fake answers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I now see the problem with omitting the virtual destructor, thanks! I also see the problem with the global variable. Is there a way to circumvent this while still having this default approach?